# 301 Redirect for Query String on Root?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have tried multiple methods of trying to redirect some URLs with a query string on the root, for example, if I try to match the URL `http://example.com/?bloginfo=racing`

```
Redirect 301 "/?bloginfo=racing" http://example.com/racing
```

or

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/?bloginfo=racing$ http://example.com/racing
```

The condition will never match. Is there a good method for this inside of my `.htaccess` file to write this kind of redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match the query string you need to use mod_rewrite and check the QUERY_STRING server variable in a `RewriteCond` directive. mod_alias directives (ie. `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` match the URL-path only, not the query string).

For example, to redirect `http://example.com/?bloginfo=racing` to `http://example.com/racing` you could do something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bloginfo=racing$
RewriteRule ^$ /racing? [R=302,L]
```

The trailing `?` on the *substitution* is required in order to remove the query string from the request, otherwise, it is passed through to the target URL. Alternatively, use the `QSD` flag on Apache 2.4+

Change the 302 (temporary) to 301 (permanent) if this is intended to be permanent and only when you are sure it's working OK (to avoid caching problems).

To make this more generic and redirect `/?bloginfo=<something>` to `/<something>` then you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^bloginfo=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /%1? [R=302,L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the captured subpattern in the last match *CondPattern*.

Comment: This was exactly what I as looking for. Very educational as well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Query string is separate variable from Request URI, so you will have to do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} bloginfo=racing 
RewriteRule ^$ /racing [L,R]
```